# Error when run rviz

Tags: ros, rviz, compile

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

When i'm going to run rviz, it sometimes breaks showing this error:

The program 'rviz' received an X Window System error.
This probably reflects a bug in the program.
The error was 'BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter)'.
(Details: serial 22 error_code 9 request_code 137 minor_code 3)
(Note to programmers: normally, X errors are reported asynchronously;
that is, you will receive the error a while after causing it.
To debug your program, run it with the --sync command line
option to change this behavior. You can then get a meaningful
backtrace from your debugger if you break on the gdk_x_error() function.)
[rviz-1] process has died [pid 2540, exit code 1].
log files: /home/alonso/.ros/log/72e5fea2-8403-11e1-ad7f-0018de214925/rviz-1*.log

I've got Ubuntu 10.10 and i don't know why sometimes breaks and the other times no :S.

I read this post: http://answers.ros.org/question/2775/rviz-crashing-at-startup-with-baddrawable

But it didn't solve it... I also recompiled e reinstalled rviz but either...

Any idea to solve it?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31663/error-when-run-rviz/) by [alonsosjumper](https://answers.ros.org/users/2135/alonsosjumper/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9 on 2012-04-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have a look at [rviz troubleshooting](http://ros.org/wiki/rviz/Troubleshooting) as well. I assume that it's a problem with your graphics card driver. Do you have 3d acceleration?

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-04-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alonsosjumper](https://answers.ros.org/users/2135/alonsosjumper/) on 2012-04-18**:
My graphics card is Intel GMA 950 GM. I think it's 3d acceleration. The strange is the problem only appear sometimes, not always... I saw which you told me but it's not solved...

**Comment by [alonsosjumper](https://answers.ros.org/users/2135/alonsosjumper/) on 2012-04-18**:
My graphics card is Intel GMA 950 GM. I think it's 3d acceleration. The strange is the problem only appear sometimes, not always... I saw which you told me but it's not solved...